# General expression for smallest surface area of cube at any volume

Tags: calculus, optimization

The question is pretty simple but I feel like this is hard to answer and requires multivariaboe calculus of 3 variables, with A constraint a•b•c=V.
The point here is, that V is unknown. Is it possible to find a general expression which will find the smallest possible surface area at any Volume? Thank you

Comment: Do you (or the problem) intend a cube, where all of the dimensions are the same, or a *rectangular parallelepiped*, where the length, width, height may be different?  If the former, and if the dimension of each side is $x$, then you should be able to express both the volume and the surface area in terms of $x$.

Comment: I'm guessing, by the wording of the problem, that the *rectangular parallelepiped* is intended; otherwise, the problem becomes trivial.  I am also assuming that you are to assume a fixed volume $V$.  This means that $V$ is **not unknown**, but instead is a fixed constant.  This means that you are to compute the minimum surface area, in terms of $V$.

Comment: The problem reduces to : if $(a \times b \times c) = V$ (a fixed value), then what is the minimum surface area possible.  Do you know the formula for the surface area of a *rectangular parallelepiped*, which is equivalent to the surface area of $6$ rectangles?

Comment: Quick guess.  By symmetry all sides are squares of the same size so $a=b=c=V^{1/3}$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Good guess, that will probably bear fruit.  Note that the opposite *guess* that the surface area is **maximized** when the dimensions are a cube is not really tenable.  Simply imagine a volume of $1$, and dimensions $\frac{1}{1000000} \times 1000 \times 1000$.  However, the OP still has to **prove** the result.

Answer (score 1):

Elementary calculus will suffice.
The proof should be easy enough if done in two steps.

Fix one edge and use elementary calculus to show minimum is achieved when other two are equal.  $c$ fixed.  $ab=V/c$ minimize $ab+ac+bc$
or find a to minimize $V/c+ac+V/a$.  $(a^2=V/c)$

Repeat process for third edge with other two equal. $c=V/a^2$ and minimize $a^2+2ac$ or find $a$ to minimize $a^2+2V/a$. $(a^3=V)$.

You get $a=b=c=V^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the question asks to maximize for a cuboid (and not a general parellopiped.)

$ V = abc \land S = ab + bc + ca$

$
\begin{align}
S &= ab + bc + ca = V(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c})\\
&\geq \frac{3V}{V^{1/3}} = 3V^{2/3}
\end{align}
$

Second line follows from GM-HM inequality, and equality occurs when $a = b = c$.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, I assume it is a cuboid, but not a general parallelopiped.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll edit my answer accordingly.